Can a voltage higher than LED maximum be used when using constant-current LED driver?
I am planning to use these components:

TLC59283
CREE J Series 5630 LEDs

Specifically, I want to create a setup like Figure 9-1 on pg. 22 of the TLC59283 datasheet. Currently, I am trying to choose a LDO to supply the voltage for the LEDs - named VLED in the referenced figure.
The issue is, the maximum forward voltage for the CREE LEDs is 2.9V (pg. 9 of the CREE datasheet) and I was hoping to reuse the output of a 3.3V LDO that will also supply my MCU.
My question is, can I make VLED 3.3V even though the maximum voltage for the LEDs is 2.9V if I set the constant current sink of the TLC59283 to something like 35mA (way less than the 240mA max on pg. 9 of the CREE datasheet).
Thanks for your time.

A constant current sink is essentially a programmable resistor.  If you set the supply voltage to the LED forward voltage then you would have (nearly) zero volts across the resistor and thus zero current through the circuit.  Just like the classic battery and resistor LED circuit, you need the supply voltage to be larger than the LED forward voltage to set the current with a resistor.

What Voltage do you have in front of the LDO? And can the LDO deliver the required current without overheating? If your primary suppply is no >10V you can attach the LEDs to that and use the 3.3V as VCC for the TLC59283.

@kruemi My device will be plugged into a 5V supply. I will use the 3.3V LDO for the TLC59283 and MCU (spec'ed for the max current of both devices). For the LEDs, I will supply them directly with the device 5V input. From what I can tell, as long as the voltage applied to the TLC59283 outputs is less than 10V, everything will work (pg. 6 Table 5.4 'VO'). If I supply 5V to the LEDs with 2.9V voltage drop than I will have 2.1V applied to the outputs. Looking at pg. 11, Figure 5-5 also confirms this as the output current/LED current remains constant no matter the voltage on the outputs.

The sink driver requires 0.8V to get guaranteed output current, so for 2.9V maximum Vf LEDs you should have 3.7V supply voltage minimum.
It won't hurt the LEDs but you might not get full current or it might not be consistent or as stable with temperature as it might be.

Ok, the forward voltage of the LED is amount the voltage drops over the diode. If we place 3.7V (VLED) on the anode/+ of the diode and it drops a maximum of 2.9V we get 3.7-2.9 = 0.8V on the cathode/-. Looking at pg. 7 at Voutn, we need that voltage for the driver to start sinking our target current (35mA). If I want to target different currents, all I should need to do is change the value of RIREF (pg. 16), correct?
Thanks!

Correct. You can (and probably should) have at least a bit more voltage, of course.
